# How can I add a song to my playlist of songs with file explorer Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I'm develop a music player and one of the funtions is that you have to press a button and open a file explorer and then when you select a song it needs to add to the current playlist but I don't know how to add it. Actually I only get the path but I don't know how to add the song to my list

The app has 3 songs from raw directory and when I click another one in my file explorer needs to add

Here is my code the file explorer works fine and it gives the path of the file

```
public void openFile(View view){
new ChooserDialog().with(this)
        .withFilter(false, false, "mp3", "wma", "wav", "jpg")// para agregar mas formatos solo agregar un nuevo elemento despues de "wav" eje: "wav", "mp4" ....
        .withStartFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()) // ruta en la que inicia el buscador
        .withChosenListener(new ChooserDialog.Result() {
            @Override
            public void onChoosePath(String path, File pathFile) {

                Toast.makeText(Explorador.this, "FILE: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .build()
        .show();
```

}

And here is my variables and my method onCreate

```
ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp;


int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;
SeekBar positionBar;
TextView TiempoInicio, TiempoFinal, titulo;
int totalTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorador);

play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay_Pause);
listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lv);
TiempoInicio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTiempoInicio);
TiempoFinal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTiempoFinal);
titulo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);


registerForContextMenu(listaCanciones);

list = new ArrayList<>();

//Agregar a la lista las canciones de la carpeta raw
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    list.add(fields[i].getName());
}


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, list);
listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if(mp != null ){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }

        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Explorador.this, resID);
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Poner el nombre de la cancion
        titulo.setText(listaCanciones.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());



    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 3):

First of All create these classes:

```
abstract class Song{
    public void play();
    public void stop();
}


class StorageSong extends Song{
    private String pathName; //with getter and setter

    public void stop(){//stop the local storage song file}
    public void play(){//play the local storage song file}
}


class RawSong extends Song{
    private String rawName; //with getter and setter

    public void stop(){//stop the raw song file}
    public void play(){//play the raw song file}
}
```

Now change these lines:

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    list.add(fields[i].getName());
}
```

to these ones:

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    list.add(new RawSong(fields[i].getName()));
}
```

And When you want to add a local storage file do something like this:

```
list.add(new StorageSong(file_path));
```

And treat your list as an ArrayList of < Song > in your adapter or activity. Is my suggestion clear? any questions?